# Linux gvim vs vim

Tags: linux, vim, editor, vi

is there a difference between gvim and vim on a linux machine ?

I installed an enhanced version of VIM editor which includes recent enhancements:

> vim-enhanced-2:7.2.411-1.8.el6(x86_64)

And after installation, I could see *.viminfo* and *.vimrc* in my home directory. I even made changes on *.vimrc* and intentionally put some wrong codes in there and it errored out. So, I know for sure that it is calling *.vimrc* upon invoking vim.
I also had a *.vimrc* from past for GVIM, and I copied that file into this new *.vimrc*, and again there is no complain.

So far so good.

But now, when I open VIM, it opens the file in the terminal! And it is not opening a new window for GVIM. But I can see that it has almost all of GVIM capabilities!

How could I make this open in a separate window when I open a file?

Comment: Normally `vim` opens a command line program and `gvim` opens a GUI program (often an alias for a binary e.g. `vim-gnome`).  Did you use to have it so that `vim` would open a GUI program?

Also, check `:help ex` in vim to get an idea of the different aliases vim has for starting up.

Comment: what is the question? you want to know the diff between gvim and vim? or want to get a gvim window if you type `vim foo.txt` ?

Answer (score 37):

if you are asking the difference between vim and gvim... there are some (personal opinions):

### color support

vim runs in terminal, if you set up your terminal correctly, vim supports 256 (or 88) colors. however gvim can support from `000000 - FFFFFF` colors.

### difficulty of some key mappings

again, depending on the terminal you used. some key mapping may be difficult to achieve. E.g. I wanted to map insert mode `alt-i/j/k/l` in my vim, I tried a lot, unfortunately, so far it doesn't work for me. But in gvim it is much easier.

### gvim is easier to be started by other GUI applications

(plugins may needed)
like browser or other IDEs

### Gvim needs X

You can start vim as long as you can get a terminal. even tty or pts. But with Gvim you have to have GUI installed.

### with vim you can get benefit from `ctrl-Z`

if you want to test your codes in shell/terminal, or execute some shell commands during your editing. In vim you can just `ctrl-z` to back to terminal do what you want, and `fg` back to vim. With Gvim, you cannot do that.

### it is great work with vim in tmux/screen

When you are in gvim, you have that single window, switching to other program/application is not as easy (read comfortable) as vim in tmux/screen.

There may be more, but at this point I just think of those. Personally 90% time I use vim.

Comment: The benefit of last two points (Ctrl-Z and tmux) is entirely subjective. When I'm in terminal-only I'll use them; but often I'll use a terminal and MacVim (gVim), and Command-Tab (Alt-Tab) between them - which is, for me, easier than both tmux navigation and Ctrl-Z/fg.

Comment: @Amadan . yes they are subjective.  I have most time x env but tmux for me is more convenient than alt tab

Comment: I also can't get `map <M-k> dd` to work in vim while `map <M-Down> dd` works.

Comment: Wow, i didn't know about ctrl+Z and `fg`, this thing is pretty big deal, as i close and open vim to run commands pretty oftenly(when ssh in server). And yes, i use tmux too.

Answer (score 5):

On some systems, `gvim` is just `vim -g`: you can edit a file in a GVim window from your shell with `$ vim -g filename` or simply `$ gvim filename`.

On other systems, like RedHat IIRC, `vim` and `gvim` are two different executables built at the same time with the same features: you can edit a file in a GVim window from your shell with `$ gvim filename`.

Either way, you should try to get your hands on a more recent build because 7.2.411 is almost exactly four years old and quite a lot happened in the mean time.